# Collision detection for an arc of a circle

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection, collision

So how do i implement the collision detection for an arc of a circle? Will i have to use the Box 2d collision or can i do it some other way using Rectangle or stuff like that?

BTW I hate box2d because i dont understand most of the things in it, so if there is a solution that excludes the box2d, it will be very much appreciated.

[image: yellow arc circle]

The yellow arc keeps on rotating over the black circle. How do i implement collision detection in here?

Please help ! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid using Box2D you could define the shape as a polygon and use the [polygon.contains(x,y)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html#contains-float-float-) method or use the [Intersector](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html)

Below is an example using both:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Circle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Polygon;

public class Test extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor{
    private ShapeRenderer sr;
    private Polygon polya;

    private boolean isColliding = false;
    private Circle mp;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        //define arc as polygon 
        // the more points used to define the shape will 
        // increase both required computation and collision precision
        polya = new Polygon();

    // create vertices
    float section = 15f;
    float[] newVerts = new float[200];
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        newVerts[i*2] = (float)Math.sin(i/section); //x 0 to 98 even
        newVerts[i*2+1] = (float)Math.cos(i/section); //y 1 to 99  odd

        newVerts[199-i*2] = (float)Math.cos(i/section); //x 100 to 108
        newVerts[198-i*2] = (float)Math.sin(i/section) + 0.2f; //y 101 to 199

    }

    polya.setVertices(newVerts);
    polya.scale(50);
    polya.setOrigin(1, 1);
    polya.rotate(60);

        //define circle to act as point for checking intersections
        mp = new Circle(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,4);
        // setup batchers
        sr = new ShapeRenderer();
        sr.setAutoShapeType(true);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // check collision with polygon
        isColliding = polya.contains(mp.x,mp.y);

        //check collision using Intersector
        isColliding = Intersector.isPointInPolygon(polya.getTransformedVertices(),0,polya.getVertices().length,mp.x,mp.y);


        sr.begin();
        sr.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        if(isColliding){
            sr.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
        sr.polygon(polya.getTransformedVertices());
        sr.circle(mp.x,mp.y,mp.radius);
        sr.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        int newy = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY;
        polya.setPosition(screenX, newy);
        return false;
    }


    (... removed unused input processor methods for clarity ...)
}
```

Comment: Alright i run your code so i could see what you have made, so i saw i arc made your polygon which i found pretty cool btw :) but my question is i am rotating my arc so i will have to rotate my polygon too how do i do that?

Comment: You can rotate the polygon using polya.rotate(degrees); you may also need to set the origin so it rotates around the right point polya.setOrigin(originX, originY); I added them to the example.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the arc was in motion and I needed to calculate its collision, so I updated the polygon along with the rendering. Essentially, **I got the vertices in the same way that *`LibGDX`* renders an arc**.

On the left you can see what the arcs I'm drawing look like. On the right you can see what **the polygons would look like calculated from the shape of their corresponding arcs** if I had to draw them.

[image: Just arcs]
[image: Arcs polygons]

*Ignore the different colors and count of sections, they are randomly generated.*

To achieve this result, I wrote this method:

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Polygon;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

// ...

public void fillPolygonWithArc(Polygon polygon, float x, float y, float radius, float start, float degrees, int segments) {
    float theta = (2 * MathUtils.PI * (degrees / 360.0f)) / segments;
    float cos = MathUtils.cos(theta);
    float sin = MathUtils.sin(theta);
    float cx = radius * MathUtils.cos(start * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
    float cy = radius * MathUtils.sin(start * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);

    ArrayList<Vector2> vertices = new ArrayList<>();

    vertices.add(new Vector2(x, y));
    vertices.add(new Vector2(x + cx, y + cy));
    for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
        vertices.add(new Vector2(x + cx, y + cy));
        float temp = cx;
        cx = cos * cx - sin * cy;
        cy = sin * temp + cos * cy;
        vertices.add(new Vector2(x + cx, y + cy));
    }
    vertices.add(new Vector2(x + cx, y + cy));

    cx = 0;
    cy = 0;
    vertices.add(new Vector2(x + cx, y + cy));

    polygon.setVertices(new float[vertices.size() * 2 + 4]);

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
        polygon.setVertex(i, vertices.get(i).x, vertices.get(i).y);
    }
}

// ...
```

> How does he work?

> It takes as parameters a polygon in which to write the vertices of the
> arc and the parameters needed to get the shape of the arc, these are
> the same parameters that you pass to the method that draws the arc (`shapeRenderer.arc`).
>
> And then it calculates the vertices of the arch in the same way as
> *`LibGDX`* does and fills the polygon with them.
>
> I just looked at the *`LibGDX`* source.

Use case:

```java
fillPolygonWithArc(polygon, getPosition().x, getPosition().y, getRadius(), start, finalStep, getSegments());

shapeRenderer.setColor(color);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRenderer.arc(getPosition().x, getPosition().y, getRadius(), start, finalStep, getSegments());
shapeRenderer.end();
```

Also, if you want, you can draw a polygon:

```java
fillPolygonWithArc(polygon, getPosition().x, getPosition().y, getRadius(), start, finalStep, getSegments());

shapeRenderer.setColor(color);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.polygon(polygon.getVertices());
shapeRenderer.end();
```

Ultimately, you can check if some point is inside the polygon you need:

```java
polygon.contains(new Vector2(4, 20));
```