# Creating a circular Orbit in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, gravity, orbit

I am trying to implement Gravity in my game.
I currently have a Moon which should orbit a planet (both using the class Cell in my game).

The following code is used (shortened):

In class Cell:

```
private Cell graviator;
private Vector2 pos;
private Vector2 vel;
private Vector2 drg;
private int mass;
private float drgSpeed;
private GravityField grav=new GravityField(this);

public void move(){
    calculateDrag();
    if(orbiting){
        orbit();
    }
    pos.add(vel);
    pos.add(drg);
}

private void calculateDrag() {
    drg.scl(drgSpeed);
}

private void orbit(){
    Vector2 temp=new Vector2(drg.x,drg.y);
    temp.rotate90(0);
    temp.nor();
    speed=(float)Math.sqrt((mass+graviator.getMass())/getGraviatorDistance()); // v= sqrt((M*m)/r)
    temp.scl(speed);
    vel=temp;
}
```

In class GravityField:

```
private Cell cell;

public void computeGravity(Cell cell2) {
    float force = getForce(cell2);
    if (cell != cell2.getGraviator()) {
        if (cell2.getMass() < cell.getMass()) {
            if (force > cell2.getLargestForce()) {
                cell2.setGraviator(cell);
                cell2.setLargestForce(force);
                cell2.setDrg(getDragVector(cell2));
                cell2.setDrgAcc(getAcceleration(cell2));
            }
        }
    } else {
        cell2.setLargestForce(force);
        cell2.setDrg(getDragVector(cell2));
        cell2.setDrgAcc(getAcceleration(cell2));
    }
}

public Vector2 getDragVector(Cell cell2) {
    Vector2 temp = new Vector2(cell.getPos().x - cell2.getPos().x, cell.getPos().y - cell2.getPos().y);
    temp.nor();
    return temp;
}

public Vector2 getDirection(Cell cell2) {
    return new Vector2(cell.getPos().x - cell2.getPos().x, cell.getPos().y - cell2.getPos().y);
}

public float getDistance(Vector2 direction) {
    return direction.len();
}

public float getForce(Cell cell2) {
    Vector2 temp = new Vector2(cell.getPos().x - cell2.getPos().x, cell.getPos().y - cell2.getPos().y);
    return cell.getMass() * cell2.getMass() / (temp.len() * temp.len()); //f = M*m/r^2
}

public float getAcceleration(Cell cell2) {
    Vector2 temp = new Vector2(cell.getPos().x - cell2.getPos().x, cell.getPos().y - cell2.getPos().y);
    float force = cell.getMass() * cell2.getMass() / (temp.len() * temp.len());
    float acceleration = force / cell2.getMass(); // a= f/m
    return acceleration;
}
```

So with my GravityField i am basically applying a dragVector to the pulled Cell.

In Cell, the Cell is moved towards the graviator with

```
 pos.add(drg);
```

and towards its own movementVector vel with

```
pos.add(vel);
```

In my orbit() method I am trying to find and set vel to make an circular orbit.

My problem is that I somehow cant archieve a perfect orbit. The Moon is still slightly and by shrinking distance increasingly accelarated towards the planet.

I can´t figure out why it is not working. Do I use the right formulas?

Written out I used:

`v= sqrt((M*m)/r)` for my OrbitVector speed
`f = M*m/r^2` for the force puling towards the planet
`a= f/m` for the acceleration towards the planet

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple. There are 2 textures you are going to need, your orbit and the moon. What you have to just do is keep rotating the moon over the orbit.

If you are using the sprite , you can do so:

```
sprite.setRotation(rotationVaue);
rotationValue+=1;
```

But a very important thing to note here is that both the image should have the same resolution .

I recently did the same thing, i even asked a question about it on stackoverflow , here is the link:

[Collision detection for an arc of a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775650/collision-detection-for-an-arc-of-a-circle)

Comment: Well that´s not exactly what i want.
I am trying to implement a physics system. The orbits should be dynamic and support mulitple influencing stellar bodys..